# The slideshow works well if I stay in the same browser tab, and becomes not well If I moved to another tab

Tags: javascript

My slideshow works well if I stay in the same browser tab which slideshow exists in, but If I change the Browser tab to another and then back again to the slideshow tab I find that the slideshow moves randomly And in a wrong way. I don't know what happened to the slideshow.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="slideshow">
  <img src="images/img.jpg" alt="" title="" />
  <img src="images/img2.jpg" alt="" title="" />
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var time = 0;
var slideshow = function() {
    var slideshowElem = document.getElementById('slideshow');
    var slideshowLen = slideshowElem.children.length;
    var slideshowScrollheight = slideshowElem.scrollHeight - 300;
    if (slideshowElem.scrollTop < slideshowScrollheight) {
      time = setInterval(function() {
        slideshowElem.scrollTop += 5;
        if (slideshowElem.scrollTop == slideshowScrollheight)
          clearInterval(time);
      }, 10);

    } else {
      time = setInterval(function() {
        slideshowElem.scrollTop -= 5;
        if (slideshowElem.scrollTop == 0)
          clearInterval(time);
      }, 10);
    }
    setTimeout(slideshow, 3000);
  }
  // implementation
slideshow();
```

Can anybody know why that happened, although I think my code is correct?

Comment: If you leave the browser, setInerval and setTimeout are paused, that may lead to problems

Comment: Modern browsers will pause javascript timers to save resources.

Comment: Using a short interval isnt a good idea, concerning performance. Use css transitions to make it smooth and fast

Comment: Consider that `setTimeout` and `setInterval` only guarantee a _minimum_ time before firing.  Pretend for a second that you have timeouts of 3000 in your `setInterval` calls.  Now the `setTimeout` may fire again before you have called `clearInterval`, leaving an additional slide up (or down) running alongside the new one.  This is essentially what's happening when the browser throttles the timers - when you're on the window, the intervals are probably cleared fine, but away from the tab you enter race condition territory.

Comment: I thank everyone, now I have known cause of the problem, but I want to know a way to solve it.
@JamesThorpe: Unfortunately, I don't understand your idea.

Comment: It's not an idea to solve the problem, it's just trying to illustrate that you have a basic race condition going on.  You need to simplify your use of `setTimeout` / `setInterval`.  Or perhaps it's as simple as calling `clearInterval(time)` before both `time = setInterval` lines.

Comment: @JamesThorpe: I think I have done what you said, but the problem still.

Comment: Is there is any radical solution for that problem, because I am not capable of creating any slideshow because of that problem?

Comment: Well css transitions -> more stable + more easy